# Translate Module Angular 10 The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, ngx-translate

this is `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
  }

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
              deps: [HttpClient]
            }
          })
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

this is `toolbar.component.html` where i'm using translation.

`<span>{{'shared.settings' | translate}}</span>`

In `toolbar.component.ts` I imported

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

I don't know why, I obtained this error (i'm using Angular 10)

> ERROR Error: The pipe 'translate' could not be found!

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the `TranslateModule` (not with `forRoot()`) in whatever `NgModule` the `ToolbarComponent` is declared. So for instance, if it's declared in its own module, you would have to do the following. Otherwise the component does not have access to the pipe:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ToolbarComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ToolbarComponent
  ]
})
export class ToolbarModule {}
```

Or if you use a `SharedModule` that you import in multiple other feature modules, which is common practice, you can export the `TranslateModule` to make sure you don't have to import it in every module.

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes but I always get the same error

Comment: i solved add `"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false }` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm migrating from Angular4 to Angular12

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes restarting the IDE may help.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:-

add "angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false } in tsconfig.json